3 Aspects of Voltage that contradict each other
I feel like I really don't get voltage:
There are three understandings of voltage, which makes sense independently and relate to each other but also at the same time don't fit in:

Voltage is Potential Difference: Voltage is the difference between the energy levels. A charge flows from high potential  to low potential. Technically as a charge move towards the positive end, it loses potential energy as it is converted into electrical energy. If resistance increases then the p.d increases because it would take more energy for a charge to move back from the positive end to the negative end

Voltage as per Ohms Law (V= IR). Voltage is the work done on a charge. If resistance is 0 then so is the voltage. Why is that. If resistance is infinity then so is the current. Isn't a potential difference needed for current to flow. Is the logic above true and apply here that since there was no energy to move it back there would be no release. This doesnt makes sense but perhaps it is the nature of electricity

Resistance reduce Voltage/ Voltage Drop. The voltage before and after a resistor should decrease because the electron has done work, and thereby lost the potential energy, but it doesnt fit in with understanding 1. Should the voltage drop of a circuit equal to the voltage. Like increasing the resistance means there is more voltage drop, so the total voltage drop will be equal to p.d. How does this fit in with a battery that has a fixed voltage


Also what really is the difference between Ohm's law and potential difference

Not "answering" because I'm not really an expert.  I have a mechanical background and didn't understand voltage for a long time.  But I find it helpful to think of it as the analogy to pressure in pipe flow.
"If resistance is 0 then so is the voltage. " - I would say, rather, "If resistance is 0 then so is the voltage DROP."  Or, "If resistance is 0 then so is the necessary voltage to produce current."   The latter is true for superconducting magnets which maintain current indefinitely with zero resistance.

To Nr 2: $V=I*R$ is not a definition of V but the definition of resitance transformed R is defined by $R=\frac{V}{I}$

To build on @trula's comment. What your equation means is, when there is a resistor, the voltage needed to push a current through a resistor is V. The equation is trivially true for infinite resistance, but it's meangless because other effects become primary. For example, an arc ladder can be said to have an infinite resistance between the rods, but an infinite voltage isn't needed to exceed the air gap breakdown voltage, causing the arc. So, one of the reasons you're having trouble is your view is as yet incomplete.

One more thing, @trula's version of the equation is important because it better reflects what's going on. An infinite R requires any voltage at all divided by zero current, which is what you'd expect (that the voltage drop no longer matters).

Basically the problem here is using the same words for similar and related concepts that are nonetheless not identical. The fundamental concept that is behind "voltage" is the concept of electric potential. The electric potential of a system is the scalar field $\phi$ such that $\vec{E}=-\nabla \phi$. This is the formal definition and you may not be familiar with it. The point is that the electric potential is a field that has a value for every point in space, and it is closely related to the electric field. This is why people say that the "voltage" after a resistor is lower (in the case of a positive charge flowing from high potential to low potential), that's because the electric potential is lower. They are using "voltage" to talk about "electric potential".
So, what is voltage? Voltage is the electric potential difference between two points, $V=\Delta \phi$. The voltage of a battery is the difference in electric potential between the poles of a battery. The voltage between the ends of a resistor is the difference in electric potential between the ends of a resistor, etc. That is, the first definition you give is the correct one. But so is the second definition, because a difference in electric potential is also work done per unit charge between two points. That's also correct, but it might be less intuitive. Why is it true? Well, if you know the integral definition of electric potential and the integral definition of work, it shouldn't be too hard to follow this derivation
$$V =\int_{P_1}^{P_2}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=\int_{P_1}^{P_2}\frac{\vec{F}}{q}\cdot d\vec{l}= \frac{W}{q} .$$
Regarding your third point, in the case of an ideal circuit with a single battery and a single resistor, the voltage drop accross the resistor is always equal to the voltage of the battery. That's always the case because of Khirchoff's first law, regardless of the resistor or the battery. The thing that changes if you change either of those is the current. If you have more than one resistor, for example, now the voltage drop accross each of those is not equal to the voltage of the battery, and it depends on their resistances.

if you use the ball in a hill, analogy  the electric potential decreases independent/regardless of the resistance or friction. In Electricity, the Electric Potential decreases as an electron goes towards the positive end. So why wouldnt a voltmeter show a decrease in p.e, ignoring resistant

Conventional current assumes positive charges instead of electrons, and therefore the charges go from higher potential to lower potential. You can work with the reverse assumption but it will be less intuitive.


1- Voltage is Potential Difference: Voltage is the difference between
the energy levels.

The potential difference between two points is the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points.

A charge flows from high potential to low potential. Technically as a
charge move towards the positive end, it loses potential energy as it
is converted into electrical energy.

The first statement applies to the flow of positive charge, known as "conventional current". The second statement is incorrect for positive charge. It gains potential energy. It is correct for negative charge (electrons).
When a negative charge (electron) moves towards the positive end it loses potential energy. When a positive charge moves towards the positive end it gains potential energy.

If resistance increases then the p.d increases because it would take
more energy for a charge to move back from the positive end to the
negative end

If resistance increases it requires more work per unit positive charge to move the charge through the resistance. Not sure what you mean by "move back".

2-Voltage as per Ohms Law (V= IR)

Ohms law doesn't define voltage. It describes the relationship between voltage, current, and resistance.

Voltage is the work done on a charge.

Again, the voltage (potential difference) between two points is the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points.

If resistance is 0 then so is the voltage. Why is that.

Since there is no resistance to current flow, no work is required  to move the charge.

If resistance is infinity then so is the current. Isn't a potential
difference needed for current to flow.

I don't know what you mean by the first statement. If there is resistance then a potential difference is needed for current to flow.

Is the logic above true and apply here that since there was no energy
to move it back there would be no release. This doesn't makes sense
but perhaps it is the nature of electricity

See my previous answers.

3- Resistance reduce Voltage/ Voltage Drop. The voltage before and after a resistor should decrease because the electron has done work, and thereby lost the potential energy, but it doesn't fit in with understanding 1.

Understanding 1 is incorrect, or at least inconsistent. See my previous answer.

Should the voltage drop of a circuit equal to the voltage.

Seems like you might be thinking about Kirchhoff's voltage law. The algebraic sum of the voltages around a closed circuit is zero. The sum of the voltage drops equals the some of the voltage rises.

Like increasing the resistance means there is more voltage drop, so
the total voltage drop will be equal to p.d. How does this fit in with
a battery that has a fixed voltage

Increasing the resistance in a circuit increases the voltage drop only if the current is the same. But for a fixed voltage source, increasing the  resistance on one resistor in a series circuit with other resistors reduces the current and voltage drop across that resistor.

Also what really is the difference between Ohm's law and potential
difference

Answered above.
Hope this helps.

A good answer but the asker is too confused.

@Ritzthephysibeast Yes I know. It was hard to know where to begin, so I just tried to make some adjustments in the OP's thinking.

Perhaps the best mental picture for voltage is elevation. Taking Gravitational Potential Energy $E_g= mgh$ divided by the mass, gives us Gravitational Potential:
$$V_g= \frac {E_g}{m} = gh$$
And since $g$ is constant on Earth, we can see this as simply a measure of elevation $h$.
This is the potential energy at any given point on Earth's surface, but divided by the mass, so that the mass is the object is not a factor.
Let us take a ball of $1~ \rm kg$ as our test mass.  $V_g=gh$ between two points (e.g. on a hill) is the potential difference between those points. $V_g$ is also the potential energy gained by the $1~ \rm kg$ mass if it is moved from the lower to the higher point, and $V_g$ is the work done to raise it from the lower to the higher point. In addition, if we talk about water flowing down a hill, a steep hill with $V_g = 5$ will cause more flow per second than a shallower hill with $V_g = 1$.
Now, electrical potential $V_e$ is exactly the same thing, but for a charge in an electric field instead of a mass in a gravitational field:
$$V_e = \frac {E_e}{q}$$
The electrical potential difference (voltage) $V_e$ between two points tells you how much energy a charged particle of $1~ \rm C$ will gain or lose when traveling between those points.
As in the water example, a higher $V_e$ equates to a steeper slope, and will cause more electrical current.
When a resistor is assigned a voltage drop, that means the charges in the current will lose that much energy (per $1~ \rm C$) by passing through the resistor.
In an electrical DC circuit, the current begins on the high voltage (+) side of the battery, which is the highest voltage in the circuit, then travels through the circuit losing voltage the whole way – sometimes in big jumps like in a resistor, or else gradually in the wire - and ends in the low voltage (-) side of the battery. The battery, in a way, is like a pump that boosts the current back up to the high elevation to begin its journey again.
[Technically the battery redistributes charge internally to cancel the charge that went through the circuit, but you can picture it as stated.]
[One more note: the actual term for the quantity described is electrical potential difference (or electrical potential).  "Voltage" began as an informal term because potential is measured in Volts, just as people will say "acreage" when they mean the surface area, because area was often measured in acres. But do not let this cause you confusion as if voltage were a distinct entity.]


(Electric) potential energy $U$ is associated with a charge $q$ and its location in an electric system.
(Electric) potential $V=U/q$ is (electric) potential energy per charge, a measure that makes it easier to compare different points.
Voltage $\Delta V=V_2-V_1$ is (electric) potential difference and is typically the only measure that matters.

With these properties in mind, let's consider the foundations from an intuitive perspective:
A battery is a little electrochemical "machine" that moves negatives charges to one pole, in rough terms. An electron at this negative pole is strongly repelled; it feels a great electric force pushing it away - they have nowhere to move, but if they could, they would. This tendency of "wanting to move" is what we call potential energy $U$ or just potential $V$. The greater the tendency to move, the higher the potential.
The other pole does not show large repulsion against the electron. So the potential associated with this pole is low in comparison.
If you connect the poles with a conducting wire, the electron will move immediately. Had both poles been at the same potential, then it would have no tendency to move since the repulsion would be the same everywhere. Of that reason we consider the difference in potential, the voltage $\Delta V$, sometimes also symbolized with $V$, though.
You can think of voltage as "electric pressure". The higher it is between two points, the greater is the electric force that a charge would feel towards that other point.
Now, charges will accelerate wildly along this wire since the electric repulsion forces just keep on pushing unresisted. Soon the wire would melt. If you add a resistor - like a filter that the charges must "squeeze through" - then that will slow them down. Other charges will have to queue up behind the resistor and a similar thing happens after the resistor, so soon all charges move at the same speed. Meaning, the current is the same everywhere. This is a so-called steady state.
Note that a very small voltage would make the charges move with ever-growing speed along the wire, but now the resistance will slow it down, so a certain amount of voltage is needed to achieve a certain current. Of that reason we refer to this necessary voltage as a voltage drop, as if the resistance "uses up some of the voltage". Meaning, a certain "electric push" is needed through the resistor which corresponds to a certain voltage across it. Charges at other points would not need such "push" since nothing is slowing them down - only charges through the resistor would need it.

Now to your three points.
I agree with 1., although we generally think of charge as positive and not by default negative. A point of high potential would for a negative charge be a negatively charged point, but for a positive charge it would be a positively charged point. Keep this in mind.
To your point 2., you are considering a steady state, where currents and voltages have stabilized. Here charges need no extra "push" from one point to another, unless there is a resistance in between, thus there is a voltage of zero, between any such to points. The points might still be associated with high potential, but their potentials are equal. So zero voltage. Current will still flow since nothing is slowing it down. This corresponds to $R=0$.
On the other hand, if you cut the wire then that would correspond to $R$ being infinite. That would result in zero current, $I=0$, since nothing can flow.
To your point 3., increasing the resistance on the wire will necessarily reduce the current, since the charges are slowed down even more but the "electric push" is still the same. You could change to another battery that could supply a greater voltage, and then achieve the same current again. This all fits with Ohm's Law.
